# StreamReader breaking on special character

Tags: node.js, encoding, character-encoding, fs

I'm trying to read a file in a meteor-app on the server with `fs`.

**My goal:**
I want to process a very big file. Therefore I need to read it line by line to keep the memory usage flat.

**My approach:**
I'm creating a streamReader and processing the file for each character, saving it to a new string until I get a `\n`, then passing it to a `processLine(line)` function.

**My test-file:**

```
F1;F2
12;abäde
```

**My code:**

I've commented everything out thats out of scope of the problem. Anyway posting it just in case someone has a complete different way for me.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// ...

let streamReader = fs.createReadStream(path, { highWaterMark: 1});

let line = "";
streamReader.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk)
    // line += chunk;
    // if (chunk == "\n") {
    //     processLine(line);
    //     line = "";
    // }
});

streamReader.on('end', function() {
    processLine(line);
});

processLine = (line) => {
    console.log(line);
}
```

**Output from the code above:**

```
F
1
;
F
2



1
2
;
a
b
�
�
d
e
```

Either tho the docs are saying the default encoding is `utf8` the character `ä` prints out as `�`.

**Output when specifying the encoding like below:**

`fs.createReadStream(path, { highWaterMark: 1, encoding: "utf8 }`

```
F
1
;
F
2



1
2
;
a
b
```

It is breaking when reaching the `ä`. I think this happens because it would need 2 chunks to represent that character.

I just dont know how to get around it. In general I just need to process it line by line. Maybe I've taken the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiny values of the high water mark don't save a significant amount of RAM; the default values are something like 32k anyway.  And, to try to use the highwater mark to enforce an old-timey `getchar()` operation is to misuse it.

[There's a `readline` object in core node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline).  It accepts output from a stream and splits it into lines.  [The documentation offers some samples](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line). This is adapted from the samples **not debugged**.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface(
   {
          input: fs.createReadStream(path),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
   })

rl.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log(`A line: ${line}`);
})

rl.on('close', function () {
  /* file completely processed */
} )
```

It is also handy for interactive commmand line input/output, but you don't care about that here.

Comment: Oh that looks good. According ram: I've got files of about 600-1000 MB. Char by char isnt important, line by line is! I'll try that out in a few hours. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Works perfectly. Ty very much!